# sql query Case when example

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, case

I need to write a sql query which is as follows :
select name as NAME ,
(something) as customer_id from table;

table has 3 columns for customer_id depending on the type of customer.So i check serially which ever id column in not null , i take it as customer_id
So something block in above query is as follows:

```
(CASE 
      WHEN ID1 != null THEN ID1
      WHEN ID2 != null THEN ID2
      WHEN ID3 != null THEN ID3
      ELSE null
    END) as customer_id.
```

But the query always returns null for customer id . Am i missing something here or any better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `not null` rather than `!= NULL`:

```
(CASE 
  WHEN ID1 is not null THEN ID1
  WHEN ID2 is not null THEN ID2
  WHEN ID3 is not null THEN ID3
  ELSE null
END) as customer_id
```

Any comparison to `null` (with just a few exceptions) returns `NULL`.  And a `NULL` boolean value is treated as false.

A better way to phrase this is using `coalesce()`:

```
coalesce(ID1, ID2, ID3) as customer_id
```

Comment: Thanks :) . One more question regarding this . I will be using these queries in writing Native queries (JPA) . So is it ok to use coalesce() . I mean is it supported by all the database ?

Comment: @user3417179: AFAIK, it is supported by all SQL.

Comment: @user3417179 . . . `coalesce()` is an ANSI standard function supported by most databases.  Some do not, particularly old versions, but most modern and common databases do support the function.  And, I think that all databases that support `case` also have `coalesce()`.